# Adobe AIR containing SWF

Tags: air

I know I can include a swf in an Adobe AIR application, and communicate between the two with localConnection, but is there a better way to have the swf communicate with the application containing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can embed the SWF in the AIR application and instantiate the classes inside the SWF within  AIR application.

[Embedding with Flash](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/articles/embed_metadata.html?PID=5232140)

[Embedding Assets in AS3](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=embed_4.html)